# How do sites like yelp and urbandictionary prevent double voting from non-logged in users?

Tags: javascript, jquery

You don't need to be logged into urbandictionary to upvote a definition.
For example goto 
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=meters
upvote the first word. it records it supposedly. then open up incognito mode, goto the same URL, try to upvote again, it detects you already voted.
You can even open up firefox or another browser and goto the same page and it detects you already upvoted.

Same goes for yelp when clicking on useful/funny/cool..

how are they doing this?
are they actually recording the IP of the users and checking to make sure they haven't double voted on each upvote click? it seems so fast, like a client-side javascript implementation, but how are they detecting I already voted if I opened up a new incognito session?

it seems there is a GET request w/ callback param value something like this jQuery17108145102619146468_1379449108386

edit: they must be recording the IP. My coworker just opened the link and it said he already voted when he tried to upvote. (and he had never even visited the site before. I also confirmed our external IPs are the same)

Comment: Consider all of the client-side tracking mechanisms employed by an [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) -- surely some of them persist between incognito sessions. Local shared objects (LSOs) provided by Flash are a likely candidate

Answer (score 1):

May be it is using evercookie.

Please see the link below:
http://samy.pl/evercookie/